# android - Passing message from broadcast to activity

Tags: android

I was reading some post but none have a good answer for me.

So, which is the best way to pass data from broadcast to activity without restart the activity?

Actually I'm using this.

SMSListener:

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver  {
private OnSmsReceivedListener listener = null;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    try {
        if (Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                for (SmsMessage smsMessage : Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)) {
                    String messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
                    String phoneNumber = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onSmsReceived(phoneNumber, messageBody);
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Error", "Some some");
    }
}

public void setOnSmsReceivedListener(Context context) {
    this.listener = (OnSmsReceivedListener) context;    
}
}
```

OnSmsReceivedListener:

```
public interface OnSmsReceivedListener {
void onSmsReceived(String sender, String message);
}
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnSmsReceivedListener {
   private SmsListener receiver;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        /***********/
           receiver = new SmsListener();
        receiver.setOnSmsReceivedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSmsReceived(String sender, String message) {
        Log.e("Test", "Sender: "+sender+" - Message: "+message);
    }

}
```

Another of my questions is why I never get log "Test" in my activity. Is like listener is always null, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add at the end of `onCreate()`

```
final String SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION);
registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

and in the onPause()

```
unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```

add also the following permission on AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```